# call method after dot, not in parenthsis

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Assume I have a function:

```
Protected Sub UploadFile(file As String)
    .......
End Sub
```

Then I can do the follwing

```
UploadFile(file)
```

But I would like to do this:

```
file.UploadFile()
```

Looks like Im missing logic in here, but still - is it possible to make dot-like notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want an Extension method.

```
Module StringExtensions
  <Extension()> 
  Public Sub Upload(ByVal fileName As String)
      ' ... Upload the file, now.
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to use extension method instead of regular method?

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to add an extension method to such a common class.  It would clutter up the intelisense pretty fast.  However, in some cases it makes your code more fluent.  See if you can limit the scope of the method so it only appears when you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that upload file is a method you're trying to invoke on the same class you defined it on. If that's the case, all you have to do is

```
 this.UploadFile();
```

and adjust the UploadFile() method to read the file from a member variable instead of a parameter.

Hope that gives you enough info to get started.